# React Child Component should Not Update After Parent State Change

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 components parent and child
if child component  state changes then the child component should be updated (rerender),
if the parent component  state changed then the child component should not be updated   (rerender)

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your child component `React.memo`: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

Comment: I want to render the child component on its own state change,on that time parent should not rerenderd.

Comment: Do you try as my answer?